# How do I create new column with list

Tags: php, list, html-lists

This should be a really simple one, but just cant get it to work. I have a database with lets say 20 items. I am using php to echo each item. my code is :

```
echo "<li> <a class='bodylinks' href='http://domain.co.uk/fish/$txt2/'>$txt</a> </li>";
```

My problem is that my page only has height for say 14 of the items, however I have spare width. How to I make it move over to the right creating a new column when the height is maxed out on the other column? Hope this makes sense.

At the moment it just displays down to the 14 item then because I have `overflow:hidden` on the containing DIV it cuts the rest off.

Comment: Question is not descriptive, Please improve your question.

Comment: chill out, is understood and answered :)

Comment: @Ajay you comment was not very helpful either to be honest.. which part was not clear? If i have worded it the best way i can and you cant understand it then it would be helpful if you could tell me which are parts are not clear. Further more -1 is a bit harsh when its clear i am new to the site.

Comment: @andrewanderson May be I could not figure out and thought you need to add more description. By the way nice to see the response thanks to mschr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use floats

try this, it will print out your list items horizontally from ltr (default direction) and drop to next line - vertically.

```
<li style="display:inline;"> contents </li>
```

alternatively, make your loop count 14 rows, then at 14th, close your UL/OL tag and create a new one like so:

```
<ul style="display:block; float:left;">
<?php
for($i = 0; $i = count($results); $i++) {
    $txt = $results['txt']; // or however you do
    $txt2 = $results['txt2']; // or however you do
    if($i > 0 && $i % 14 == 0) echo '</ul><ul style="display:block; float:left;">';
    echo "<li> <a class='bodylinks' href='http://domain.co.uk/fish/$txt2/'>$txt</a> </li>";
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `($i > 0 && $i % 14 == 0)` will give a modulo of zero on 14th, 28th, 42nd etc rows

Comment: You have to account for screen size and resolution. Sure, 14 rows is what displays on his monitor, but what about other monitors sizes?

Comment: i take it from your answer that there is not a css/html attribute which creates a new coloumn if the current one is used up? 

I am just a bit worried about what paul has suggested about screen sizes.

Comment: I have just accepted defeat and created a new <ul> to hold the overflow. thanks for the help :)